# Cauchy Riemann equation

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I've done part (a) as it simply involves stating the Cauchy Riemann, however part (b), im assuming I would have to apply this and therefore for part (i) let $u'=(u^2-v^2)$ and $v'=2uv$

would this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
(u + iv)^2 = (u^2 - v^2) + 2i uv
$$
If $f(x+iy)$ is complex differentiable, is $f(x+iy)^2$?

Comment: therefore it is differentiable as the product of differentiable functions are differentiable?

Comment: Yes, assuming that your book has proved that. If it hasn't then you can check that Cauchy-Riemann equations hold for $f^2$.

Comment: oh okay in that case I would assume that I would have to check it using Cauchy Riemann equations

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $h = (u+iv)^2, g = \overline {u+iv}.$